# Jenkins agent without Docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, agent, slave

I'd like to set up Jenkins agent on machine with Windows Serwer 2012 RC2. How I read, this Windows didn't support Docker. Can I create agent without Docker? How it worked before Docker? Do You have any ideas? :) Does the virtual machine on Windows and then other OS with Docker it's the only way?

Answer (score 2):

After [adding a new node](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/#setup-up-the-agent1-on-jenkins) in the controller instance, [click on it under the builder executer status panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnOfs.png) and you will get this screen

[image]

You can download the agent.jar by clicking on it and then follow the instructions to execute it using java only.

Also by inspecting the [repo for the docker image](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-agent/blob/master/windows/nanoserver/Dockerfile) you can check that the agent jar versions are available [here](https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/main/remoting/) currently.

Couldn't find proper documentation on this.

Comment: I found some old documentation similar to your instructions: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step-by-step-guide-to-set-up-master-and-agent-machines-on-Windows.html